# How to make angular application safe if you need important vars and parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I am still new to Angular apps and wonder about some security concerns and would appreciate some tips on how to handle this.

Lets say I access my Amazon S3 Server from my Angular Application. That for I need to write somewhere my bucketname, accesskey and secret key... but since it is all visible to the user everybody can see the secret key which does not make him anymore secret of course.

I can also not use something like a SALT etc. to create user passwords for the same reason. All is visible in the end and even with minify and uglify anybody can reverse it as well.

What is the best approach to do things like this? So far I can only think of one thing and this is to not use javascript or angular at all in this cases and for example only access my S3 bucket via PHP. But this cant be the only way I hope?

For Firebase it looks the same problematic since everybody can see all infos right away and can connect basically to my DB and than add for example information he want to. Of course I can setup rules and make certain things obligated but this can be also sniffed out easy inside my code at the end which seems all pretty unsafe if I compare this to a php/mysql backend.

Comment: You don't want to store sensitive information like access keys in front end,  store them in backend.

Comment: As your client side code is visible by anybody, you should definitely manage this in you backend

Comment: Just to make clear what we talk about. If I for example want to upload an image to S3 from my angular application than I cant do this direct because I cant store the access key/secret key inside my app. I first need to send the image to my php backend and from there to S3?

Comment: How would be the situation if I request the access keys from my php backend via SSL first, than use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Cordova SecureStorage plugin to store access and/or session tokens:

https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

Since the Android implementation of this secure storage uses the KeyStore, the users must have a secure screen-lock set (like fingerprint, pattern or PIN). The plugin provides functions to check this, so you will be able to give a warning (or block login) if this is not the case. Without a locked screen there is **no** way to save your keys in a secure way on Android.

Comment: Thank you @JanP this is very interesting and I check it out. Defiantly a option to store the data on the device. My concern is mainly how I can access safe s3 storage or do other server connections without being able to store the access keys and passwords inside the application since they would be readable.

Comment: I think the level of security you need highly depends on the functionality you wish. Buckets can be configured to only accept certain file types and content can be removed after a certain time. But if you want to keep the AWS keys private, then let your app retrieve the keys from your PHP backend over SSL and store them in secure storage. They will be stored encrypted. If necessary, you could add user validation to your PHP backend.

Comment: I understand. My plan is now to first authenticate the user via firebase/auth and after successful login I retrieve some important vars from my php backend via HTTPS, I keep them only inside the sessionStorage  (ngStorage) until the user leaves the application. Once he comes back I retrieve them again fresh. I am not talking about a major application here with high security standards but I want to keep the basics in order. Can I work like this?

Comment: Yes, you can work like that, but in stead of ngStorage, use secure storage. Unless you don't want to force the Android users to lock the screen of their device. But in that case you would have to accept a lower level of security.

Comment: That is a working solution for my mobile app. Remains one doubt. I also have a angularjs web aplication which serves as for the administrator to manager some things. Since this is not a mobile app I cant use your cordova plugin in this case. Do you have something similar for plain angular web aplications? Or how should I handle the storage in this case?

Comment: I think there are roughly three options: setting a cookie, localStorage or sessionStorage. In your case I would recommend sessionStorage as it will be destroyed automatically after closing the session.